# Raspberry Pi white screen after several days what is the problem

Tags: pi-3b+, touchscreen

I have a Raspberry Pi that is connected to a touchscreen via HDMI.

After several days the screen becomes white and it does not work anymore.

When you reboot the Pi it works again.

The Pi is used to display a webpage.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I once had a similar problem. The cause was a faulty HDMI cable, with one wire intermittently breaking when over bent, and/or heated up. It took me some time to narrow down the faulty cable. I replaced the cheapy HDMI cable with a good quality one and problem disappeared, and me and the HDMI display live happily ever after. This was my first troubleshooting experience with HDMI display a couple of years ago, so I remember my ereka joy vividly as it happen yesterday.  Just sharing my experience. Of course you might have other trouble to shoot. Good luck.  Cheers.

Comment: Of course there are other possibilities. Here is another: Rpi's HDMI interface connector actually has a very small power supply that powers some configuration circuit at the HDMI display side, so to check the configuration of the HDMI display, even BEFORE the display is switched on, ..  Now the Rpi's small current voltage regulator might heat up some how, now might not be powerful enough if your cheapy HMDI cable's wiring is too thin, causing excessive voltage drop. Anyway, try another cable, or another monitor. Cheers.

Comment: What generation of the Raspberry Pi do you own?